# Does count() cause map() code to execute in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

So, I know that Spark is a lazy executor.
For example, if I call

`post = pre.filter(lambda x: some_condition(x)).map(lambda x: do_something(x))`

I know that it won't immediately execute.

But what happens to the above code when I call `post.count()`? I imagine the filtering would be forced into execution, since `pre` and `post` will likely not have the same number of rows since there is a `filter` condition there. However, `map` is a 1-to-1 relationship, so the count would not be affected by it. Would the `map` command be executed here given the `count()`?

Follow up: When I want to force execution of `map` statements (assuming `count()` doesn't work), what can I call to force execution? I'd prefer to not have to use `saveAsTextFile()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`count` will execute all transformations in the lineage unless some stages can be fetched from cache. It means that every transformations will be executed at least once so along as you don't depend on some kind of side effects triggered by `some_condition` or `do_something` it should work just fine.

Comment: Does this mean, given the command above, that I should be doing a `pre.cache()` somewhere higher up (for example, when I create `pre`), so that it doesn't re-execute the lineage that created `pre` when I call `post.count()`? (This assumes I also have to do something with `pre` before it goes on to be used in `post`.

Comment: If pre is not a ShuffledRDD then yes.

Comment: If `map` is the last operation for an RDD, shouldn't it skips calling the `map` function for 'count()' optimization since its a 1 to 1 mapping unless `map` is being called as `pre.filter().map().filter()` or there are other transformation like `flatmap` which could result in 1 to many mapping? Haven't checked the source code which evaluate the `count()`

Comment: @AnchitChoudhry Should or could? Theoretically it could. But there is no guarantee that the function  used in `map` is side effect-free (where exception is the simplest kind of side-effect here). Unless programming model is restricted (like `DataFrame` API) the only optimization which is applied is merging multiple transformations into a single stage. Scala collections apply some other other tricks later on but it is not Spark specific.